# Concatenate an IF Statement with certain cell

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation, textjoin

I'm trying to concatenate the cell E46 at the end of this statement if this IF statement is true. Can't seem to get it to function.

=IF(J46="OOT",ServicePlannerContacts!$E$83,"")

Comment: `=IF(J46="OOT",ServicePlannerContacts!$E$83 & E46,"")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in two ways according to [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/combine-text-from-two-or-more-cells-into-one-cell-81ba0946-ce78-42ed-b3c3-21340eb164a6):

1. `IF(J46="OOT",ServicePlannerContacts!$E$83 & E46,"")`
2. `IF(J46="OOT",CONCATENATE(ServicePlannerContacts!$E$83,E46),"")`